# There is no error reported when using the BigQuery API to read data, but the result of the query is inconsistent with the Bigqeury Table

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I try to read my table data using BigQuery API. When I use the increase mode, the data is accurate, but when I use specify, the data will be wrong, the specific error is:
The data on April 1 and April 2 should be 50893 and 50327 respectively, but the data actually inserted into the clickhouse is only 5000 on April 2, and the total is indeed correct, it's getting me nowhere.
This is my code

```
package com.addcn.app.dws;

import com.google.cloud.bigquery.*;
import com.addcn.utils.CreateAuthorizedClient;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import picocli.CommandLine;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;

import static com.add.common.access.*;

public class RevenueSaleValueUsed implements  Runnable{

    private static final Long PAGE_SIZE = 15000L;

    @CommandLine.Option(names = {"-d", "--dataset"}, required = true, description = "Bigquery need dataset")
    private String datasetId;

    @CommandLine.Option(names = {"-t", "--table"}, required = true, description = "Bigquery need table")
    private String tableId;

    @CommandLine.Option(names = {"--type"}, required = true, description = "Please enter your update policy! full increase specify")
    private String type;

    @CommandLine.Option(names = {"--startdate"}, description = "if you choose specify, Please choose it")
    private String startDateStr;

    @CommandLine.Option(names = {"--enddate"}, description = "if you choose specify, Please choose it")
    private String endDateStr;

    @CommandLine.Option(names = {"--key"}, description = "key")
    private String key;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RevenueSaleValueUsed rsvu = new RevenueSaleValueUsed();
        CommandLine.run(rsvu, args);
    }


    private static String buildQuery(boolean isFullUpdate, TableId sourceTableId,
                                     LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate, long offset) {
        if (isFullUpdate) {
            return String.format("SELECT * FROM `%s.%s` LIMIT %d OFFSET @offset",
                    sourceTableId.getDataset(), sourceTableId.getTable(), PAGE_SIZE);
        } else {
            String dateCondition = String.format("event_date BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s'", startDate, endDate);
            System.out.println(String.format("SELECT * FROM `%s.%s` WHERE %s LIMIT %d OFFSET @offset",
                    sourceTableId.getDataset(), sourceTableId.getTable(), dateCondition, PAGE_SIZE));
            return String.format("SELECT * FROM `%s.%s` WHERE %s LIMIT %d OFFSET @offset",
                    sourceTableId.getDataset(), sourceTableId.getTable(), dateCondition, PAGE_SIZE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println(sdf.format(System.currentTimeMillis()));

        LocalDate startDate = null;
        LocalDate endDate = null;
        boolean isFullUpdate = false;

        String credentialsPath = System.getenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS");
//        String credentialsPath = this.key;
        if (credentialsPath == null || credentialsPath.isEmpty()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable is not set.");
        }

        TableId sourceTableId = TableId.of(datasetId, tableId);

        if (type.equals("increase")) {
            startDate = LocalDate.now().minusDays(1);
            endDate = LocalDate.now().minusDays(1);
        }

        if (type.equals("full")) {
            isFullUpdate = true;
        }

        if (type.equals("specify")) {
            startDate = LocalDate.parse(startDateStr);
            endDate = LocalDate.parse(endDateStr);
        }

        try {

            Connection clickhouse = DriverManager.getConnection(CLICKHOUSE_URL_DEV, CLICKHOUSE_USER_DEV, CLICKHOUSE_PASSWORD_DEV);

            String sql = "INSERT INTO t8891." + tableId + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

            PreparedStatement insertStmt = clickhouse.prepareStatement(sql);

            BigQuery bigQuery = CreateAuthorizedClient.createAuthorizedClient(NEWCAR, credentialsPath);

            int offset = 0;

            while (true) {

                String query = buildQuery(isFullUpdate, sourceTableId, startDate, endDate, offset);

                QueryParameterValue offsetParam = QueryParameterValue.int64(offset);

                QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig = QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(query)
                        .setDefaultDataset(sourceTableId.getDataset())
                        .setUseLegacySql(false)
                        .setPriority(QueryJobConfiguration.Priority.BATCH)
                        .setMaxResults(PAGE_SIZE)
                        .setNamedParameters(ImmutableMap.of("offset", offsetParam))
                        .build();

                TableResult result = bigQuery.query(queryConfig);

                for (FieldValueList row : result.iterateAll()) {
                    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(row.get("event_date").getStringValue());
                    insertStmt.setObject(1,date);
                    String itemId = row.get("item_id").getStringValue();
                    insertStmt.setString(2,itemId);
                    insertStmt.setInt(3,(int) row.get("num_exposed").getLongValue());
                    insertStmt.setInt(4,(int) row.get("num_click").getLongValue());
                    insertStmt.setInt(5,(int) row.get("num_browse").getLongValue());
                    insertStmt.setInt(6,(int) row.get("num_contact").getLongValue());
                    insertStmt.setInt(7,(int) row.get("num_mobile_contact").getLongValue());
                    insertStmt.setInt(8,(int) row.get("num_im_contact").getLongValue());
                    insertStmt.setInt(9,(int) row.get("num_line_contact").getLongValue());
                    insertStmt.setInt(10,(int) row.get("num_confirm").getLongValue());
                    insertStmt.setInt(11,(int) row.get("num_mobile_confirm").getLongValue());
                    insertStmt.setInt(12,(int) row.get("num_line_confirm").getLongValue());
                    insertStmt.setInt(13,(int) row.get("num_im_confirm").getLongValue());
                    insertStmt.addBatch();
                }

                insertStmt.executeBatch();

                System.out.println("总行数：" + result.getTotalRows());

                if (result.getTotalRows() < PAGE_SIZE) {
                    System.out.println(sdf.format(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    insertStmt.close();
                    clickhouse.close();
                    break;
                } else {
                    offset += PAGE_SIZE;
                    System.out.println("offset:" + offset);
                }
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("ClickHouse exception: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Failed to read credentials file: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println("Query job was interrupted: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This is command:
`java -cp bigquery-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.add.app.dws.RevenueSaleValueUsed -d=dws -t=dws_item_performance _daily --type=specify --startdate=2023-04-01 --enddate=2023-04-02`

I tried to print out the SQL, and then run it on the BigQuery client, the result is correct, but the program is corrected when running

```
System.out.println(String.format("SELECT * FROM `%s.%s` WHERE %s LIMIT %d OFFSET offset",
                    sourceTableId.getDataset(), sourceTableId.getTable(), dateCondition, PAGE_SIZE, offset));
```